# Splitting a vectorized image of letters into individual letters

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, typography

I'm trying to digitize a handwritten font.  In various tutorials, it says to ungroup and then click on the rectangular background's blue box and press delete and it should leave all the characters as individual vectors.  When I do this, it just deletes the whole photo instead of leaving the individual vectors.  How do I get these letters to be separate entities?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi efajcz, is this already a font file (.ttf, .woff, .otf)?

Comment: I've currently saved it as a jpeg, not these formats.

Comment: Hi efajcz, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Could you please clarify a bit more? Have you `Image Trace`d the .jpg first? If we know more, we can more easily identify your problem. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Try to `Object > Expand Appearance` and `Object > Ungroup` first, the latter possibly multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a jpeg, you will have to turn each letter into a vector.

The quick way but not very good way of turning a jpeg into a vector is by going to `Object -> Image Trace -> Make`.

[image: Image trace options]

Red: You can then select `Image Trace Panel` to fine tune the selection. This will bring up a window where you can select options so Illustrator knows how you want the image trace to work.

Green: Once you have messed with the Image Trace Panel, you can then expand the image. Press `Expand`.

Once you pressed expand, you can then select the object/group and `right click -> ungroup`. You will now have each letter own its own.

However the results are less than desired for small images.

See results

[image: font image trace results]

---

Another option would be to trace the individual fonts with the pen tool `P`. You can set the anchor points and trace over your font image. This will be a lot more time consuming but you will get much better and consistent results.

---

There are some online converters out there that will transform text into a font but I imagine they will not be any better than image trace from illustrator.

Comment: I've already traced the jpeg.  What do I do next?

Comment: @efajcz how? Did you trace with the pen tool, brush with tablet, image trace or another option?

Comment: I used Image Trace in Illustrator CS6.

Comment: @efajcz See edit or just select object and right click ungroup. You will first have to make sure the image trace is expanded.